# How to fill in empty dates following a Pandas groupby operation?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset that contains entries with many columns, one of which is the date of the entry. In most cases, if a date has at least one log, it is likely to have multiple logs. However, there are also many gaps in the dates represented (e.g., There may be entries for January 20th with the next entry being February 2nd, with all dates in between having zero entries).

To analyze each date's entries, I use the pandas groupby operation to group the data by date. I'm now wondering how I can go about filling the resulting groupby object with the missing dates, assigning each of them a single row with null or 0 values.

Comment: please provide an example dataset and the expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code given that you don't provide any specific code

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
# Convert date to datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
# Set date as index and sort if required
df = df.set_index('date').sort_index()

# Although there is a way with resampling,
# the fact that you have duplicates complicates things,
# so you can create date ranges and join on them
dates = pd.date_range(start=df.index[0], end=df.index[-1], freq='1d')
dates = dates.to_frame(name='date').drop(columns=['date'])
df = dates.join(df, how='left')

for date, group in df.groupby(df.index):
    print(group, end='\n\n')
```

Prints

```
                 data
2017-01-01  somedata1

           data
2017-01-02  NaN

           data
2017-01-03  NaN

                 data
2017-01-04  somedata4

           data
2017-01-05  NaN

           data
2017-01-06  NaN

                   data
2017-01-07  somedata7_1
2017-01-07  somedata7_2

           data
2017-01-08  NaN

           data
2017-01-09  NaN

                  data
2017-01-10  somedata10
```

I used the following csv

```
date,data
2017-01-01,somedata1
2017-01-04,somedata4
2017-01-07,somedata7_1
2017-01-07,somedata7_2
2017-01-10,somedata10
```